# Path change without reloading the route + allow back button to reload the route (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, routes

So I am trying to be able to change the $location.path of my app without reloading the controllers etc. I found a workaround on this page:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1699

The problem is that the workaround works too well and the page does not reload when pressing the back button in the browser. Another weird issue I noticed is that when I place `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (){ ... });` in my `app.run`, it is being called over 3000 times on page load/route change...

The code that I have been using looks like this:

```
myService.skipReload = function () {

  var lastRoute = $route.current;

  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
    $route.current = lastRoute;
  });

  return MyService;
};
```

Then I use it like this: `myService.skipReload.changePath(url);` where `changePath(url)` simply contains `$location.path(url)`.

Edit: I found an ugly workaround, in app.run I wrote:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {

  $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.path();
});


$rootScope.$watch(function () {return $location.path()}, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
  if($rootScope.actualLocation === newLocation) {
    myLocationService.refreshView();
    console.log('Use of history back, may not always work...');
  }
});
```

Let me know if there is a better way to do this.