# AngularJS change url with $location

Tags: angularjs, url, location

I'm trying to change the URL with AngularJS,
but not with a redirect, just change the URL 
after an event.

What I need is this:

`www.myurl.com/inbox/1` to this `www.myurl.com/inbox/25`

In other words, just change the last Id.

I'm trying to do this:

`$location.path('/inbox/'+id);`

But what I'm getting is this:

`www.myurl.com/inbox/1#/inbox/25`

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002984/angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load

Comment: I don't want redirect

Comment: This is the best I could do with our app:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940106/path-change-without-reloading-the-route-allow-back-button-to-reload-the-route

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Angular enforces the idea of one page web app. Browsers don't take any actions on change of anything after '#' value. So the best practice is to add variable attributes in url after '#' value which will keep the base url and attribute look clean on browser's address bar as well as solve your problem. My advice is to keep username, page no. , or any specific attribute id after '#' value. 
In your case you should use something like above said

### www.myUrl.com/#/inbox/25

or

### www.myUrl.com/inbox/#/25

Answer (score 19):

usually angular URLs look like

```
www.myurl.com/#/inbox/1
```

in which case

```
$location.url('/inbox/25');
```

should work for you

Answer (score 0):

For that you should use .url() instead of .path()

```
$location.url(`/inbox/${id}`)
```