# Save data and scroll of previous state when opening new state in modal window (Instagram/Pinterest routing)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-bootstrap

I want to create routing like on the Instagram/Pinterest. In my case - open full article in the modal window. From [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) 
I find this code:

```
    $stateProvider.state("items.add", {
    url: "/add",
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "items/add",
            resolve: {
              item: function() { new Item(123).get(); }
            },
            controller: ['$scope', 'item', function($scope, item) {
              $scope.dismiss = function() {
                $scope.$dismiss();
              };

              $scope.save = function() {
                item.update().then(function() {
                  $scope.$close(true);
                });
              };
            }]
        }).result.then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                return $state.transitionTo("items");
            }
        });
    }]
});
```

It works ok, but when I'm closing modal window, the scroll and data of the previous state are not saved. Whether there is an existing solution that retains scroll and data from the previous state after closing modal?

Comment: If `ui-router` works like the regular ngRoute, you need to hack around to avoid your app to refresh. At least that s the issue I see here. I'll post some references in a minute.

Comment: This might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940106/path-change-without-reloading-the-route-allow-back-button-to-reload-the-route

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented "Sticky States" in ui-router-extras.  Ui-router-extras is an addon module for ui-router.  I have a modal example/demo which I believe does what you want to do.  Visit the example here:

http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/index.html#/people/manager/0/emp/25

Then check out the main ui-router-extras page here: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras